# Can I use a CTE to make these two tables become one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way I can make these two queries become one query? I need all of this to be in one table. Currently I'm not using any common table expression and I believe if I use them I can make these two codes into one single table.

I would also like a column called 'G' which is a sum of 'E' and 'F'

Is there any way I can combine these two queries into one?

This is my code for two seperate queries:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
    Code NVARCHAR(20),
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    EFFECTIVEDATE DATE,
    Reference NVARCHAR(20),
    RATE Decimal(3,2)

)

INSERT INTO @Results
SELECT
TP.Reference AS [Code],
TP.NAME AS [Name],
FORMAT(D.StartDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [EFFECTIVEDATE],
D.Reference AS [Reference],  
DR.Rate AS [RATE]                                                                                                                                                                           
FROM TradingP TP
RIGHT JOIN Schema S on S.TradingPId = TP.Id 
RIGHT JOIN Deals D ON D.SchemaId = S.Id
LEFT JOIN DealResults DR on D.Id = DR.DealId
LEFT JOIN DealTurnoverBands DTR ON D.Id = DTR.DealId

SELECT 
[Code] 'Supplier Code',
[Name] 'Supplier',
[EFFECTIVEDATE] 'Effective Date',
[A] 'A %',
[B] 'B %',
[C] 'C %',
[D] 'D %',
[E] 'E %'
FROM @Results
PIVOT (
MAX(RATE)
FOR
Reference IN ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E]) 
)
as pivottable1
```

````
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
    Code NVARCHAR(20),
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    EFFECTIVEDATE DATE,
    Reference NVARCHAR(20),
    RATE Decimal(3,2)

)

INSERT INTO @Results
SELECT
TP.Reference AS [Code],
TP.NAME AS [Name],
FORMAT(D.StartDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [EFFECTIVEDATE],
D.Reference AS [Reference],  
DTB.PercentageRate AS [RATE]                                                                                                                                                                           
FROM TradingPartners TP
RIGHT JOIN Schemes S on S.TradingPartnerId = TP.Id 
RIGHT JOIN Deals D ON D.SchemeId = S.Id
LEFT JOIN DealTurnoverBands DTB ON D.Id = DTB.DealId
WHERE PercentageRate IS NOT NULL AND PercentageRate >0.1

SELECT 
[Code] 'Supplier Code',
[Name] 'Supplier',
[EFFECTIVEDATE] 'Effective Date',
[F] 'F %'
FROM @Results
PIVOT (
MAX(RATE)
FOR
Reference IN ([F]) 
)
as pivottable1 
```
````

Comment: Why are you `LEFT JOIN`ing to `DealTurnoverBands` when it *appears* that it must return a row. You have `PercentageRate IS NOT NULL AND PercentageRate >0.1` in your `WHERE` (which might as well be just `PercentageRate >0.1`) and according to your `SELECT` `PercentageRate` is in the table aliased as `DTB`, which is `DealTurnoverBands`. If no row is returned from `DealTurnoverBands ` then is it **impossible** for the value to be `> 0.1`. Your `JOIN` is an implicit `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to have to alter the joins as I'm getting NULL results for everything apart from the code, name and date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a CTE; just insert both sets of data into your table variable.

Also, you should avoid converting a `datetime` value to a string just to remove the time portion; just cast it to `date`.

And if you're testing for records where the `PercentageRate` is greater than `0.1`, you don't also need to test whether `PercentageRate` is `NOT NULL`; a `NULL` value will not pass the greater-than test.

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
    Code NVARCHAR(20),
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    EFFECTIVEDATE DATE,
    Reference NVARCHAR(20),
    RATE Decimal(3,2)
);

INSERT INTO @Results
(
    Code,
    Name,
    EFFECTIVEDATE,
    Reference,
    RATE
)
SELECT
    TP.Reference AS [Code],
    TP.NAME AS [Name],
    CAST(D.StartDate As date) AS [EFFECTIVEDATE],
    D.Reference AS [Reference],  
    DR.Rate AS [RATE]                                                                                                                                                                           
FROM 
    TradingP TP
    RIGHT JOIN Schema S on S.TradingPId = TP.Id 
    RIGHT JOIN Deals D ON D.SchemaId = S.Id
    LEFT JOIN DealResults DR on D.Id = DR.DealId
    LEFT JOIN DealTurnoverBands DTR ON D.Id = DTR.DealId
WHERE
    TP.Reference IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
;

INSERT INTO @Results
(
    Code,
    Name,
    EFFECTIVEDATE,
    Reference,
    RATE
)
SELECT
    TP.Reference AS [Code],
    TP.NAME AS [Name],
    CAST(D.StartDate As date) AS [EFFECTIVEDATE],
    D.Reference AS [Reference],  
    DTB.PercentageRate AS [RATE]                                                                                                                                                                           
FROM 
    TradingPartners TP
    RIGHT JOIN Schemes S on S.TradingPartnerId = TP.Id 
    RIGHT JOIN Deals D ON D.SchemeId = S.Id
    LEFT JOIN DealTurnoverBands DTB ON D.Id = DTB.DealId
WHERE 
    TP.Reference = 'F'
And
    DTB.PercentageRate > 0.1
;

SELECT 
    [Code] 'Supplier Code',
    [Name] 'Supplier',
    [EFFECTIVEDATE] 'Effective Date',
    [A] 'A %',
    [B] 'B %',
    [C] 'C %',
    [D] 'D %',
    [E] 'E %',
    [F] 'F %',
    [E] + [F] 'G %'
FROM 
    @Results
    PIVOT 
    (
        MAX(RATE)
        FOR Reference IN ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F]) 
    ) As pivottable1
;
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made it clear. The value for 'F' isn't based on the same Rate. The first table uses DR.Rate and the second table uses DTB.PercentageRate.

Comment: @jdk8991 But both columns are `decimal(3, 2)`, so what's the problem with inserting both into the same `@Results` table variable?

Comment: Sorry, I will need to add  `PercentageRate Decimal(3,2)` into the @Results table  and insert `DTR.PercentageRate AS [PercentageRate]` to distinguish them. They're not based on the same Rate.

Comment: @jdk8991 You have a `rate` that comes from one column in one query, and a `rate` that comes from another column in the other query. But both are the same type. So I say again: what's the problem with putting both rates into the same column?

Comment: Apologies Richard, I was slightly confuse; I'm relatively new to sql, but thanks for the help, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Just saying, but a "Common Table Expression" or CTE is just something like a re-usable template for a sub-query.

For example, this query:

```
WITH CTE_DATA AS (select * from tableA) 
SELECT * FROM CTE_DATA AS data;
```

Returns exactly the same as this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from tableA) AS data;
```

But to combine both your queries, you can just union them in the source query of the pivot.

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT
    TP.Reference AS [Code],
    TP.NAME AS [Name],
    FORMAT(D.StartDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [EFFECTIVEDATE],
    D.Reference AS [Reference],  
    DR.Rate AS [RATE]                                                                                                                                                                           
    FROM TradingP TP
    RIGHT JOIN Schema S on S.TradingPId = TP.Id 
    RIGHT JOIN Deals D ON D.SchemaId = S.Id
    LEFT JOIN DealResults DR on D.Id = DR.DealId
    LEFT JOIN DealTurnoverBands DTR ON D.Id = DTR.DealId
    WHERE D.Reference IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') 
) 
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT
    TP.Reference AS [Code],
    TP.NAME AS [Name],
    FORMAT(D.StartDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS [EFFECTIVEDATE],
    D.Reference AS [Reference],  
    DTB.PercentageRate                                                                                                                                                                           
    FROM TradingPartners TP
    RIGHT JOIN Schemes S on S.TradingPartnerId = TP.Id 
    RIGHT JOIN Deals D ON D.SchemeId = S.Id
    LEFT JOIN DealTurnoverBands DTB ON D.Id = DTB.DealId
    WHERE D.Reference IN ('F') 
      AND DBT.PercentageRate > 0.1
) 
SELECT 
[Code] AS [Supplier Code],
[Name] AS [Supplier],
[EFFECTIVEDATE] AS [Effective Date],
[A] AS [A %],
[B] AS [B %],
[C] AS [C %],
[D] AS [D %],
[E] AS [E %],
[F] AS [F %]
FROM (
   SELECT Code, Name, EFFECTIVEDATE
   , Reference
   , RATE
   FROM CTE1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT Code, Name, EFFECTIVEDATE
   , Reference
   , PercentageRate
   FROM CTE2
) Src
PIVOT (
  MAX(RATE)
  FOR Reference IN ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F]) 
) Pvt;
```

Comment: What could I do if this is the case: `DR.Rate AS [RATE]` in CTE1 and `DTB.PercentageRate AS [PercentageRATE]` in CTE2. How could I use the pivot twice to do this?

Comment: A `UNION ALL` of 2 queries only uses the alias names of the top query. So it doesn't really matter what other alias names you use in CTE2.

Comment: Right I see, thanks for taking the time to assist me. The values for the code, name and date are pulling through. However, I'm getting NULL results for all of the other columns

Comment: The names in the pivot A, B, C,... have to match the values in the Reference column.  You should verify what values are in Reference and change the names accordingly.

Comment: Yeah they match the values exactly

Comment: Well, no idea then. Can't verify that without sample data.  Btw, I've included a criteria on D.Reference.

Comment: It worked, thank you!